# Javascript return false for link that has attribute 'href'

Tags: javascript, jquery, return-value, jquery-dialog

I've a Javascript function using ***jQuery.UI.Dialog*** for user confirmation :

```
function confirmation(selector, caption, str){
    $('#' + selector).removeAttr('title');
    $('#' + selector + ' p').html('');

    $('#' + selector).attr('title', caption);
    $('#' + selector + ' p').html(str);

    $('#' + selector).dialog({
        resizeable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'OK' : function(){
                return true;
            },
            Cancel: function(){
                $(this).dialog('close');
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

But when I call that function with :

`<a href="test.html" onClick="confirmation('conf', 'delete', 'Are you sure?');">Delete</a>`

It's always give **TRUE** value. Anyone can give me a solution?? Thanks.

Comment: The `confirmation` function has no return value. Don't you see where your `return` statements are? They're **inside** the buttons' anonymous callbacks. They have no effect on the `confirmation` function

Comment: Removing the `title` and clearing the html is not needed at all, if you are going to be setting them right afterwards anyway..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made some changes in your script. I guess making use of `return` in this case may lead to wrong interpretation because of the `async` nature. So make a call for function you want to execute for the positive as well as negative response in the `OK` or `Cancel` function itself. Here is one of the possible soultion

http://jsfiddle.net/RmM7j/1/

Comment: I can't open the page, could you move it to other site?
or just re comment this post. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return true;` or `return false;` and do actions based on the returned value. In your case, a simple approach is just execute you logic inside the callback functions. Like this:

```
function confirmation(selector, caption, str,link){
    //here I pass in the link in case you need to know which link was clicked
    $('#' + selector).removeAttr('title');
    $('#' + selector + ' p').html('');

    $('#' + selector).attr('title', caption);
    $('#' + selector + ' p').html(str);

    $('#' + selector).dialog({
        resizeable: false,
        modal: true,
        buttons: {
            'OK' : function(){
                //your logic for true case
                $(this).dialog('close');
            },
            Cancel: function(){
                //your logic for false case
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Update your html to pass in the clicked link:

```
<a id="test" href="test.html" onClick="confirmation('conf', 'delete', 'Are you sure?',this);">Delete</a>
```

I think it's better to use jquery for this:

```
$("#test").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    confirmation('conf', 'delete', 'Are you sure?',this);
});
```

Comment: Thank you @Khanh TO, but no difference result.

Comment: @Aldi Unanto: do you see my comments in code? **//your logic for true case**, **//your logic for false case**, **//here I pass in the link in case you need to know which link was clicked**.

Comment: @Aldi Unanto: check my updated answer with jquery and prevent default action of `<a>` tags

Answer (score 0):

@Aldi Unanto- when you use link tag and use the href attribute to go to another page its always execute the href whether your onclick function return false or true. So you need to href attribute set to '#' and propagate the next page call as @Khanh TO said. That is the best way to solve the issue.